# Pause video playback when user sends activity to background when intentions button is touched

Tags: java, android, video, pause

I am engineering a video player app and i seem to have a problem with the activity when ever the user leaves it either by onbackpressed() or via intentions button to use another app and maybe come back later. I want the video playback to be paused when user goes to another activity and resume exactly from where it was paused when this activity gains focus again...I have tried to override with these methods with no success please help...

```
public class video_player extends AppCompatActivity {
    VideoView main_screen;
    ListView filelist;
    DrawerLayout mydrawer;
    MediaController mc;
    TextView mytext;
    String video_name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Assign value to media controller
         mc=new MediaController(this);
        //Define VideoView
          main_screen = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoplayer);
         Uri uri= Uri.parse(first);
         main_screen.setVideoURI(uri);
         mc.setAnchorView(main_screen);
         mc.setMediaPlayer(main_screen);
         main_screen.setMediaController(mc);
          //Start playback
         main_screen.start();
     }
//method to pause video when user goes to another activity


 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     //Video can be paused but how do i save this to the outstate Bundle??
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
//method to resume playback onrestore but am clueless
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState();
    }
@Override
    protected void onPause(){
        main_screen.pause();
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        main_screen.resume();
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time reading through this and your help is greatly appreciated
}

Comment: Pleae ready acitivty life cycle first its have onResume,onStart,onDestory,onPause method and you will get your answer

Comment: Okay, am updating my code with the two methods right this instant

Comment: Implemented it as you said, still calling oncreate and the whole thing resets to default...the video to starting point etc

Comment: if you press back thats mean you are destore the activity and than you come again on the same activity so its alwys start from on create . in this case you have to save the data into local like prefrence or sql

Comment: i will look into that later but i have a solution and its the code i posted

Answer (score 1):

```
try this one 
//when your app is in background   
 protected void onPause(){
  
    super.onPause();
    main_screen.pause();   
 }


@Override
protected void onResume(){
  
    super.onResume();
    main_screen.resume();
}

//when your activity is destory 
    @Override
protected void onDestory(){
  
    super.onDestory();
    main_screen.stop(); //stop or pause what ever 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare an integer in the class that will be assigned a current Position of the seek bar of the Video in the OnPause() method and make the video seek to that integer in the OnResume() method like this...

```
public class video_player extends AppCompatActivity {
int x; 
 //Then in OnPause and OnCreate
@Override
    protected void onPause(){
        main_screen.pause();
        x=main_screen.getCurrentPosition();
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        main_screen.resume();
        main_screen.seekTo(x);
        main_screen.start();
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

This worked whenever the activity is sent to the background